# Cannot find the position of an element inside a descending order array (binary search)

Tags: arrays, binary-search

i think the logic is completely fine yet i do not know why the code does not return the position of a given element inside the descending order array using binary search.

```
#define n 9
bool found = false;
int binarysearch(int array[n],int element){
int start = 0;
int end = n-1;
int mid;
while(start<=end && !(found)){
mid = start + end / 2;
if(element==array[mid])
found=true;
else if(element<array[mid]) {
start = mid + 1;
else
end = mid - 1;
}
if(found)
return mid;
else
return -1;
}
int main (){
int array[n]={10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2};
cout << "Enter the element you want to find the position in the array " << endl;
int x;
cin >> x;
int index = binarysearch(array,x);
if(index!=-1)
cout << index << endl;
else
cout << "index not found"<<endl;
```

so whenever i input the element the result is just empty.

Comment: You have a lot of syntax errors in this code. Give us code that we can compile.

Comment: Your answer was not professional.if i spotted the errors i wouldnt be posting it here.

Comment: If I copy and paste the code you've provided here, I get a bunch of errors. It's your responsibility to make sure the code you give us reproduces the problem you're having. You said whenever you input the element the result is empty. Well, when I run the code I don't even *get* a result, the code won't even compile in the first place. So what you're saying doesn't match the code you've given us. Read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).